# Can't get Ubuntu, but customised with LiveCDCustomisation, to boot from USB without Universal USB Installer on Windows

Tags: usb, live-usb

I'm following the steps on Ubuntu's LiveCDCustomisation Wiki to make feren OS, but, when I get to booting it, it doesn't boot according to testers, **except if using Universal USB Installer on Windows**, and it's not just me, but also my buddies making Trenta OS are also getting the same problem when using this wiki, don't get me wrong, everything else works just fine, but that issue...

...it drives me so crazy and I just cannot find a way to fix it, it's a real pain in the bum though.

Comment: Are you saying this is a bug in the software? If so, please edit the question and indicate clearly.

Comment: Maybe you should treat it with `isohybrid` to make it a hybrid iso file. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/isohybrid

Comment: Ok, thanks, sudodus, I'll try it in 2017.0, but, so I can give you the answer reward, could you convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: sudodus, apparently someone isn't getting their's booting despite ISOHYBRID, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this is what I did to make the ISO work these days, plus it gives the ISO UEFI Support too:

```
cd "$LIVECDTMP"
cd ./extract-cd
sudo dd if=$UBUNTUBASEISOLOCATION bs=512 count=1 of=./isolinux/isohdpfx.bin
sudo xorriso -as mkisofs -isohybrid-mbr isolinux/isohdpfx.bin \
-V "$CDLABEL" -c isolinux/boot.cat -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 \
-boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot \
-isohybrid-gpt-basdat -o "$PRODUCTISOTARGETLOCATION" .
```

DD is there to get a working isohdpfx.bin from the Original Ubuntu ISO File used for the base, so that it can be used for the MBR image part of the ISO, and then Xorriso is used instead of mkisofs because of it has the ability to also add EFI Booting Support to the ISO.

This is personally what works now for me, and so to aid others, I might as well put the answer I found in the end for this, and to also make it so the question is then 'answered' and is no longer pending an answer...

By the way, assign UBUNTUBASEISOLOCATION to be the full path of the Ubuntu ISO file, CDLABEL to be the string name of what the ISO should be labeled when flashed or burned onto a drive, and PRODUCTISOTARGETLOCATION as the full path location of where the Created ISO should be at, for this to work properly. Also, make sure your base Ubuntu ISO has all of these files before attempting this. As far as I know, the x32 Ubuntu ISO might lack some of these files, so be sure to make sure they all exist in the base ISO first...